# Is every conformal transformation a stereographic projection of an isometry of the inverse projection?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology, symmetric-groups, conformal-geometry

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0z1fIsUNhO4) is a really nice video that shows the following:

Suppose we have a subset of $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$. Then we can project it onto the 2-sphere via the inverse stereographic projection. If we rotate or translate the sphere in the surrounding $\mathbb{R}^3$ and apply the stereographic projection again, then the result amounts to a Möbius transformation of the initial subset. Here is a screenshot to illustrate this:

$\hskip2in$
[image]

Furthermore, on [this wiki-page on conformal maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map#Complex_analysis), the 4th paragraph of the subsection "Complex analysis" says that "A map of the extended complex plane (which is conformally equivalent to a sphere) onto itself is conformal if and only if it is a Möbius transformation."

Now this seems quite interesting to me because it seems to imply that if I take a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and apply a conformal transformation $\Phi$ to it, then I can always write it as
\begin{equation}
\Phi = P\circ \phi\circ P^{-1}
\end{equation}
where $P$ is the stereographic projection and $\phi$ is a rotation and/or translation of the sphere in 3-space.

My first question is: Is that right?

My second question concerns whether this generalises to higher dimensions. I saw the wiki page on [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(conformal_mappings)) which states that every conformal mapping in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\ge 3$ is a Möbius transformation.
However, I am not sure if a Möbius transformation in higher dimensions still has the same intuitive meaning as in 2 dimensions.

Comment: Not for a *subset* of $\mathbb R^2$, no. How do you know that when you extend your transformation to all of $\mathbb R^2$ (or rather, to $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$) that you will obtain a conformal and onto map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Let $Q$ be the open first quadrant in $\mathbb{C}$, let $H$ be the open upper half plane of $\mathbb{C}$, let $f : Q \to H$ be the conformal transformation defined by $f(z)=z^2$. I'll abuse notation and write the inverse transformation $f^{-1} : H \to Q$ as $f^{-1}(z) = \sqrt{z}$. Consider the following transformation:
$$\Phi : Q \xrightarrow{z \mapsto z^2} H \xrightarrow{z \to z+1} H \xrightarrow{z \mapsto \sqrt{z}} Q
$$
and so we may write $\Phi(z) = \sqrt{z^2+1}$. This map $\Phi$ does not extend to a Möbius transformation of the extended complex plane. So, if you conjugate by stereographic projection to get $\phi = P^{-1} \circ \Phi \circ P$, then $\phi$ does not extend to any of the particularly nice functions on the 2-sphere that you ask about.

In general, conformal transformations are much wilder beasts than Möbius transformations. You might be interested in the [Schwartzian Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzian_derivative), a quantity which, given a conformal transformation between two open subsets of the complex plane, let's you measure whether that transformation is "infinitesmally Möbius". Calculating the Schwartzian derivative of $\sqrt{z^2+1}$ will show that it is not even infinitesmally Möbius, let alone the restriction of a Möbius transformation.

What you seem to have overlooked is what was mentioned in the comment of @Rahul: that theorem quoted from the wiki-page only applies to conformal ***bijections*** of $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$.

Comment: Thanks - very good answer! A last question then: This means that for a conformal transformations of $\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$, the factorisation is always possible? I mean, is it always possible to write the Möbius trf. in such an inverseProjection-rotation/translation-projection way?

Comment: Yes, and in fact this can be done with a uniformly bounded number of factors. But that's another question.

Comment: Oh wow , that is interesting. So shall I ask another question or can you recommend some reading material where this is shown? To be honest I am not sure how a uniformly bounded number of factors would look like.

Comment: I might recommend that you learn some hyperbolic geometry. As it turns out, $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ can be identified with the boundary at infinity of 3-dimensional hyperbolic geometry $\mathbb{H}^3$, and the conformal group of $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ can be identified with the group of isometries of $\mathbb{H}^3$. Then you can learn about the classification of isometries of $\mathbb{H}^3$. Once you've got that under your belt, the kind of factorization you ask for is not too much harder.

Comment: By the way, the easier case of Möbius transformations of $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ is explained in a very nice book by John Stillwell entitled "Four Pillars of Geometry".

Comment: Thanks! Would give you 2 upvotes if I could.

Answer (score 1):

(This answer was written before the large edit of the question.)

In defining a Moebius transformation $T\in{\cal M}$, $\ T(z)={az+b\over cz+d}$, you have three complex, or six real, degrees of freedom, whereas in defining a rotation of $S^2$ you have just three real degrees of freedom: You can choose the axis, and then the rotation angle. This argument already shows that there are "many more" Moebius transformations than there are rotations of $S^2$. (It is unclear to me what you mean by a translation of $S^2$.)

Where are the three real degrees of freedom lost? Number one, a Moebius transformation may have any two points $a$, $b\in\bar {\mathbb C}$ as fixed points  (there are even $T\in{\cal M}$ with just one fixed point), whereas the two fixed points of a rotation stereographically correspond to complex $a$, $b$ satisfying $a\bar b=-1$. Number two,  for a general $T\in{\cal M}$ with two fixed points one is attracting, and the other repelling, whereas for a rotation the corresponding eigenvalue satisfies $|\lambda|=1$.

Comment: Yes, a Möbius trf has 6 degrees of freedom. But I wrote that these correspond to rotations or translations of the sphere in 3-space which are in total also 6 degrees of freedom. Did you watch the video?

Comment: Furthermore, you did not fully address my question because I asked for the correspondence of conformal trf with rotations/translations of the sphere and not only Möbius trf.

Comment: But thank you of course for the answer. It still contains useful information.

Comment: I just realised you asked about the translations: With these I meant translations of the n-sphere in the embedding n+1 euclidean space before the last projection.

Comment: Are you sure that shouldn't be $a\overline b = -1$ ?

Comment: @mr_e_man: Thank you for reporting the slip.